# How to get the scope of a class in terms of starting line and end line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to check if class c uses a certain module m. I am able to get two things:
- the module's usage in that file(f),
- the starting line number of the classes in file f.

However, in order to know whether a particular class uses the module, I need to know the starting and end line of class c. I don't know how to get the end line of class c.

I tried going through the documentation of ast but could not find any method of finding the scope of a class.

My current code is:

```
source_code = "car"
source_code_data = pyclbr.readmodule(source_code)
```

This gives the following in `source_code_data` variable:
[image: source_code_data value in debugger mode][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkEFt.png)

As you can see in the image, there is lineno but no end lineno to denote the end line of a class.

I expect to get the end line of the class in order to know its scope and finally knowing the usage of the module. Currently, the module has this structure:

```
Module: vehicles used in file: /Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/generate_uml/inheritance_and_dependencies/car.py at: [('vehicles.Vehicle', 'Vehicle', 5), ('vehicles.Vehicle', 'Vehicle', 20)]
```

So, with this information, I will be able to know if a module is used in a range: used in a class.

My whole code base is:

```
import ast
import os
import pyclbr
import subprocess
import sys
from operator import itemgetter

from dependency_collector import ModuleUseCollector
from plot_uml_in_excel import WriteInExcel


class GenerateUML:
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_dict = {}  # it will have a class:children mapping.

    def show_class(self, name, class_data):
        print(class_data)
        self.class_dict[name] = []
        self.show_super_classes(name, class_data)

    def show_methods(self, class_name, class_data):
        methods = []
        for name, lineno in sorted(class_data.methods.items(),
                                   key=itemgetter(1)):
            # print('  Method: {0} [{1}]'.format(name, lineno))
            methods.append(name)
        return methods

    def show_super_classes(self, name, class_data):
        super_class_names = []
        for super_class in class_data.super:
            if super_class == 'object':
                continue
            if isinstance(super_class, str):
                super_class_names.append(super_class)
            else:
                super_class_names.append(super_class.name)
        for super_class_name in super_class_names:
            if self.class_dict.get(super_class_name, None):
                self.class_dict[super_class_name].append(name)
            else:
                self.class_dict[super_class_name] = [name]
        # adding all parents for a class in one place for later usage: children
        return super_class_names

    def get_children(self, name):
        if self.class_dict.get(name, None):
            return self.class_dict[name]
        return []


source_code = "car"
source_code_data = pyclbr.readmodule(source_code)
print(source_code_data)
generate_uml = GenerateUML()
for name, class_data in sorted(source_code_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].lineno):
    print(
        "Class: {}, Methods: {}, Parent(s): {}, File: {}".format(
            name,
            generate_uml.show_methods(
                name, class_data
            ),
            generate_uml.show_super_classes(name, class_data),
            class_data.file
        )
    )
print('-----------------------------------------')
# create a list with all the data
# the frame of the list is: [{}, {}, {},....] where each dict is: {"name": <>, "methods": [], "children": []}
agg_data = []
files = {}
for name, class_data in sorted(source_code_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].lineno):
    methods = generate_uml.show_methods(name, class_data)
    children = generate_uml.get_children(name)
    # print(
    #     "Class: {}, Methods: {}, Child(ren): {}, File: {}".format(
    #         name,
    #         methods,
    #         children,
    #         class_data.file
    #     )
    # )
    agg_data.append(
        {
            "Class": name,
            "Methods": methods,
            "Children": children,
            "File": class_data.file
        }
    )
    files[class_data.file] = name
print('-----------------------------------------')
# print(agg_data)


for data_index in range(len(agg_data)):
    agg_data[data_index]['Dependents'] = None
    module = agg_data[data_index]["File"].split('/')[-1].split('.py')[0]
    used_in = []
    for file_ in files.keys():
        if file_ == agg_data[data_index]["File"]:
            continue
        collector = ModuleUseCollector(module)
        source = open(file_).read()
        collector.visit(ast.parse(source))
        print('Module: {} used in file: {} at: {}'.format(
            module, file_, collector.used_at))
        if len(collector.used_at):
            used_in.append(files[file_])
    agg_data[data_index]['Dependents'] = used_in
'''
# checking the dependencies
dependencies = []
for data_index in range(len(agg_data)):
    collector = ModuleUseCollector(
        agg_data[data_index]['File'].split('/')[-1].split('.py')[0]
    )
    collector.visit(ast.parse(source))
    dependencies.append(collector.used_at)

agg_data[source_code_index]['Dependencies'] = dependencies
# next thing, for each class, find the dependency in each class.

'''
print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('FINAL')
for data in agg_data:
    print(data)
    print('-----------')
    print('\n')

# The whole data is now collected and we need to form the dataframe of it:
'''
write_in_excel = WriteInExcel(file_name='dependency_1.xlsx')
df = write_in_excel.create_pandas_dataframe(agg_data)
write_in_excel.write_df_to_excel(df, 'class_to_child_and_dependents')
'''
'''
print(generate_uml.class_dict)
write_in_excel = WriteInExcel(
    classes=generate_uml.class_dict, file_name='{}.xlsx'.format(source_code))
write_in_excel.form_uml_sheet_for_classes()
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: Invasive Method

I did manage to find a way to do this with `pyclbr` but it involves changing parts of the source code. Essentially you make the stack (which is normally a list) a custom class. When an item is removed from the stack (when its scope has ended) the ending line number is added. I tried to make it as un invasive as possible.

First define a stack class in the `pyclbr` module:

```py
class Stack(list):

    def __init__(self):
        import inspect
        super().__init__()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        frames = inspect.stack()
        setattr(self[key][0], 'endline', frames[1].frame.f_locals['start'][0] - 1)
        super().__delitem__(key)
```

Then you change the stack in the `_create_tree` function which is originally on line 193:

```py
stack = Stack()
```

Now you can access the ending line as well by using

```py
class_data.endline
```

---

---

---

I was not able to find a solution that uses the libraries you are using. So I wrote a simple parser that finds the start and end lines of every class contained in a module. You must pass in either the text wrapper itself or the list created by `readlines()` on your file. Its also worth noting that if a class continues until the end of the file then the end is -1.

```py
import re

def collect_classes(source):
    classes = {}
    current_class = None
    for lineno, line in enumerate(source, start=1):
        if current_class and not line.startswith(' '):
            if line != '\n':
                classes[current_class]['end'] = lineno - 1
                current_class = None

        if line.startswith('class'):
                current_class = re.search(r'class (.+?)(?:\(|:)', line).group(1)
                classes[current_class] = {'start': lineno}

    if current_class:
        classes[current_class]['end'] = -1

    return classes

import datetime
file = open(datetime.__file__, 'r') # opening the source of datetime for a test
scopes = collect_classes(file)
print(scopes)
```

This outputs:

```
{'timedelta': {'start': 454, 'end': 768}, 'date': {'start': 774, 'end': 1084}, 'tzinfo': {'start': 1092, 'end': 1159}, 'time': {'start': 1162, 'end': 1502}, 'datetime': {'start': 1509, 'end': 2119}, 'timezone': {'start': 2136, 'end': 2251}}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Which method did you end up using?

Comment: Invasive method. It made more sense to me. I was done with my own implementation but found yours better.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! The endline is really a missing feature there.

The discussion on this led to an alternative (still invasive) method to achieve this but that is almost a one-liner that does not require to subclass `list` and override the `del` operator:

https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16466#issuecomment-539664180

Basically, just add

`stack[-1].endline = start - 1`

before all `del stack[-1]` in `pyclbr.py`

Comment: that didn't work. `start` is a tuple, isn't it? also, `stack` does not have an attribute `endline`. Apologies for being too dumb here but if you could help me out with the correct(exact) code, that'd be a great help.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right `start` is a tuple containing `(lineno, indent)` So just use

`stack[-1].endline = start[0] - 1`

In Python, you are allowed to add an attribute to object during runtime even if this is frowned upon. To be nice and square, you should also modify the `__init__` functions of the structures where it is relevant. I think just `Object` ?

Sorry on my side I ended up using a different, non-invasive method (re-walk the whole ast and add the last lineno of their last desendant to each module) so I can not test this code right now.

Comment: Made the changes: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/16466/files